# Como comparar un String en Java - Java

Tags: java

Quisiera saber por que no puedo hacer que tome el siguiente `String` en la condicion `if`, la unica forma en que lo hize andar fue pasando opcion a `char` o `int` y despues aplicando una conversion.

```
Scanner kboar = new Scanner(System.in);
    String opcion;
    System.out.println("1) Crear un vagon de personas");
    System.out.println("2) Crear un vagon de carga");
    System.out.println("3) Finalizar");
    opcion = kboar.nextLine();
    if (opcion == "1")
    {
        DePasajero vdp = new DePasajero();
        System.out.println("ingrese cantidad de asientos");
        vdp.asientos = Integer.valueOf(kboar.nextLine());
        System.out.println("ingrese color");
        vdp.color = kboar.nextLine();
        t1.agregarVagon(vdp);
        System.out.println("vagon agregado");

        submenu(t1);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La clase  String se compara con la funcion `equals`

**ejemplo**

```
"hola".equals("mundo");
```

**en tu caso seria:**

```
if (opcion.equals("1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta de @x-rw es válida, creo que tu programa se puede optimizar, al tiempo que se controlan las entradas del usuario.

El siguiente programa:

- limitaría a `3` el número de opciones que el usuario puede escribir en el menú principal
- en la opción `1` controlaría que el número de vagones sea un valor numérico usando `nextInt` y de paso te evitas tener que convertir esa valor.
- se usa una estructura `switch ... case` para darle más claridad al código. Podrías incluso pasar el flujo a un método, si las operaciones dentro de la opción implican gran cantidad de código.

### Código:

```
    Scanner kboar = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion;

    while (!salir || !kboar.hasNextInt()) {

        System.out.println("1. Crear un vagon de personas.");
        System.out.println("2. Crear un vagon de carga.");
        System.out.println("3. Finalizar.");

        try {

            System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
            opcion = kboar.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de asientos:");
                    while (!kboar.hasNextInt()) {
                        System.out.println("¡Error!: Debe escribir un número. Ingrese cantidad de asientos:");
                        kboar.next();
                    }
                    int totalAsientos = kboar.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("OK, total de asientos:" + totalAsientos);
                    kboar.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese color:");
                    String color = kboar.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("OK, el color es: " + color);
                    System.out.println("Vagon agregado con: "+totalAsientos+" asientos y de color: "+color);
                    System.out.println("_______________________________________");
                    /*
                    DePasajero vdp = new DePasajero();
                    vdp.asientos = totalAsientos;//Integer.valueOf(kboar.nextLine());
                    vdp.color = color;//kboar.nextLine();
                    t1.agregarVagon(vdp);
                    submenu(t1);
                     */
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //crearVagonCarga();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Cerrando programa...");
                    salir = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 3");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("¡Error!... Debes insertar un número");
            kboar.next();
        }
    }
```

### Prueba funcionamiento normal:

```
1. Crear un vagon de personas.
2. Crear un vagon de carga.
3. Finalizar.
Escribe una de las opciones
1
Ingrese cantidad de asientos:
5
OK, total de asientos:5
Ingrese color:
Rojo
OK, el color es: Rojo
Vagon agregado con: 5 asientos y de color: Rojo
```

### Prueba funcionamiento controlando datos erróneos:

- El usuario escribe `f` en vez de un número y salta `¡Error!... Debes insertar un número`
- Luego escribe `h` en la cantidad de asientos y salta `¡Error!: Debe escribir un número. Ingrese cantidad de asientos:`

Veamos:

```
1. Crear un vagon de personas.
2. Crear un vagon de carga.
3. Finalizar.
Escribe una de las opciones
f
¡Error!... Debes insertar un número
1. Crear un vagon de personas.
2. Crear un vagon de carga.
3. Finalizar.
Escribe una de las opciones
1
Ingrese cantidad de asientos:
h
¡Error!: Debe escribir un número. Ingrese cantidad de asientos:
87
OK, total de asientos:87
Ingrese color:
Verde
OK, el color es: Verde
Vagon agregado con: 87 asientos y de color: Verde
```