# Busqueda de una Cadena en una matriz en Java

Tags: java, array, bucles

quería pedir ayuda con un ejercicio. El ejercicio tiene una funcion que recibe un argumento que es la cantidad de paises para inicializar una matriz, luego debe tener una funcion en donde el usuario ingresa el nombre de un pais, para verificar si este se encuentra registrado en la matriz.

En esta función estaba tratando de recorrer la primera columna en busqueda del argumento de la función que es el nombre que digita el usuario, dentro del ciclo hay un condicional que realiza la comparacion, si es verdadera imprime en consola que el pais esta registrado, y si es falsa imprime que no está registrado.

Lo que pasa es que el resultado de la comparación siempre me esta dando falsa, entonces aunque el pais esta en la matriz no lo encuentra. Les adjunto el código, y les agradezco mucho la ayuda

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import java.util.*;

public class practica2Examen2 {

    public static String[][] paisesRegistrados(int cantidadPaises) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombrePais;
        int puntajeActual = 0;
        String[][] paisesRegistrados = new String[cantidadPaises][3];
        for (int fila = 0; fila < paisesRegistrados.length; fila++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre el pais " + fila + ": ");
            nombrePais = leer.next();
            paisesRegistrados[fila][0] = nombrePais;
            for (int columna = 1; columna < paisesRegistrados[fila].length; columna++) {
                System.out.print("Ingrese el puntaje y posicion del pais " + fila + ": ");
                puntajeActual = leer.nextInt();
                paisesRegistrados[fila][columna] = Integer.toString(puntajeActual);
            }
        }

        return paisesRegistrados;

    }

    public static void verificacionPaises(String nombreVerificar, String[][] matriz) {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            if (matriz[i][0].equals(nombreVerificar)) {
                encontrado = true;
            } else {
                encontrado = false;
            }

        }
        if (encontrado == true) {
            System.out.println("El Pais--> " + nombreVerificar + " esta registrado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El Pais--> " + nombreVerificar + " no esta registrado");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Estás comparando Strings usando `==`. Ahí está tu problema

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como comparar un String en Java - Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151877/como-comparar-un-string-en-java-java)

Comment: Muchas gracias Alfarobravo, vieras que acabo de probar usando .equals(), y tampoco me resulta

Comment: También recibes en tu método `nombreVerificar` pero comparas con una variable `nombrePais` que para el método no existe.

Comment: Si tienes razon, disculpa, ya actualice mi codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparte de los problemas comparando instancias de String y el nombre de variable incorrecto, tu método actual sólo va a devolver `true` cuando el último elemento comparado sea el buscado.

```
public static void verificacionPaises(String nombreVerificar, String[][] matriz) {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {  // <-- nada le dice que deje de recorrer la matriz cuando lo encuentre
            if (matriz[i][0].equals(nombreVerificar)) {
                encontrado = true;
            } else {
                encontrado = false;
            }
            ...
```

La solución es detener el ciclo for cuando la comparación devuelva true

```
public static void verificacionPaises(String nombreVerificar, String[][] matriz) {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {  
            if (matriz[i][0].equals(nombreVerificar)) {
                encontrado = true;
                break; // <-- Aquí le dices que deje de recorrer la matriz cuando lo encuentre
            } else {
                encontrado = false;
            }
            ...
```

Con esto, la ejecución continuará justo después del `for`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya esta corriendo, le agradezco mucho su ayuda